# Batch, The system cannot find the batch label specified

Tags: command-line, batch, notepad++

I have a batch script with a function called `:DispLogo` in it, however, when I call it states `The system cannot find the batch label specified: DispLogo`. It is 100% there. I've tried renaming it with no success. I think it has to do with line breaks since I enabled viewing all characters in notepad++ and this is what I see in most of my files:

[image: normal]

Each new line has `CR` and `LF`. However, on the file in question, I see this:

[image]

As you can see, this file only has the `LF`. How can I fix this?

Comment: Just to confirm my understanding. *call :DisplayLogo* is supposed to go to the label *DisplayLogo*? But your screenshot simply doesn’t include that portion, is that correct?

Comment: Yes that is correct

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot and/or code copy/paste showing the section of your file that includes the `:DispLogo` label?

Comment: It seems that the line endings are important. Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232651/why-the-system-cannot-find-the-batch-label-specified-is-thrown-even-if-label-e

Comment: Sure, I’ll do it soon.

Comment: After doing some simple tests, the end-of-line sequence seems to make no difference, but if the problem is when the label straddles a block boundary, then lengthening the EOL sequence is likely to push it over the boundary, thereby suggesting that the EOL is the problem. Try adding a long `REM` statement before the label to see if this resolves it (though your editor may impose the native line endings, confusing things further).

Comment: I added `REM Had To put this here so it worked because it was straddling a block bounry, hopefuly lengthening the EOL will push it over it.` and it works now! Thanks! Could you add that as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace \n with \r\n  in your script to fix the **LF**

- \n is the line ending (**LF**)
- \r is carriage return (**CR**)
- \r\n = **CRLF**